# How does watermark work for DropDuplicates

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming

Basically I have this

```
streaming_df = (
            self.spark.readStream.format("delta")
            .option("withEventTimeOrder", "true")
            .option("skipChangeCommits", "true")
            .option(
                "badRecordsPath",
                f"{self.badrecords_path}/",
            )
            .table(f"{self.catalog_name}.bronze.measurements{self.postfix}")
            .withWatermark("startTimestamp", "72 hours")
            .filter((f.col("quality") == "Good") & (f.col("value").isNotNull()))
            .dropDuplicates(["startTimestamp", "id"])
----other transformations
```

As you could see, my watermark condition is for 72 hours.So, I would expect the latest records from today i.e 2023-07-18, not to be there in the destination (the streaming df is written to a destination delta lake table).

in case interested, this is how the destination table is being written to

```
ws = (
            streaming_df.writeStream.queryName("meas_silver_smuk")
            .foreachBatch(
                lambda df, epoch_id: process_func(
                    df=df,
                    epoch_id=epoch_id,
                )
            )
            .option(
                "checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_path}"
            )
            .trigger(**trigger_options)
            .start()
        )
        ws.awaitTermination()
```

But when I query the destination, it does have data for 2023-07-18. This is the query results of the destination:

[image]

Why is 2023-07-18 there?

As I read the documentation , the watermark, should somehow be

```
Max starttimestamp noticed - Watermark period > End Period of the time window.
```

And my time window is a processing which is done every 10 mins.

Can someone please assist in understanding? Does it still write to destination even though the watermark period is still valid and just stops the operation at the end of the watermark?

the stream writes to the destination in an append mode.

and as I see the documentation , it should be written at the end of the watermark threshold:

[image]

I could also use `dropDuplicatesWithinWatermark` and specify the Id column, but I need to get my understanding of what is happening here, first.

Any questions, and I can help answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are mentioning regarding time when output will be written is true only if you use watermark with aggregates. For `dropDuplicates` there is not reason to wait 72 hours. You immediately write unique entry and will drop all later duplicates (withing 72 hours). You will also drop the state for entries older than 72 hours from state. When you use aggregates it must wait this 72 hours as all data within it may influence aggregated value. In [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication) for dropping duplicates with watermark they don't mention this wait until watermark finish to write data they just say they drop duplicates and will check duplicates inside watermark interval.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Upvoted. Just one question before I accept this answer: So, if a duplicate record comes later than the threshold period, it will make its way to the destination table? In case of aggregates, I understand the later arriving records are just discarded based on some write-ahead logs. Is it not the same here? Meaning , I have to be extra careful, while defining the threshold, so that I ensure that duplicates would indeed not be there, in the destination?

Comment: Reading the documentation (and also your answer about removing the state entries) , makes me believe so. That if duplicate arrives later, it would make its way into the destination. So accepting the answer. Feel free to comment if that understanding is incorrect

Comment: Yes, as I understand if duplicates arrives later than 72 hours there is not guarantee that it will be removed.

Comment: According to the link here, late arrival of events after threshold Is automatically dropped. The withWatermark is just to reduce state: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html

Comment: I have now also tested it a bit. Data older than the threshold , but coming later, is indeed dropped.